# WebGrid paging not working when there is an ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I am trying to implement simple grid through an ajax call. When I click on submit on index page a grid should be displayed as a key is sent through ajax code. But when I go to page 2 the key becomes null as the code goes to controller again and grid is not displayed.
Index page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "index";
}

<h2>index</h2>
<button id="btn" onclick="divFunction()" value="submit">Submit</button>

<div id="gridcontainer">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function divFunction() {
        results();
    };
    function results() {
        $("#gridcontainer").show();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'Post',
            url: "@Url.Action("List","User")",
            data: { key: "hello" },
            begin: function () {
                $("#gridcontainer").hide();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#gridcontainer").show();
                $("#gridcontainer").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace MVCSimpleWebgrid.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult List(string key)
        {
            List<NumberModels> num = new List<NumberModels>();
            if (key == "hello")
            {
                //List<NumberModels> num = new List<NumberModels>();
                for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
                {
                    NumberModels nu = new NumberModels();
                    nu.index = n;
                    num.Add(nu);
                }
                return View(num);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WebGrid code:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.NumberModels>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
}

<style type="text/css">
    /*Here we will add css for style webgrid*/
    .webgrid-table {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border: solid 1px #98BF21;
        background-color: white;
    }
    .webgrid-table td, th {
        border: 1px solid #98BF21;
        padding: 3px 7px 2px;
    }

    .webgrid-header {
        background-color: #A7C942;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .webgrid-footer {
    }

    .webgrid-row-style {
        padding: 3px 7px 2px;
    }

    .webgrid-alternating-row {
        background-color: #EAF2D3;
        padding: 3px 7px 2px;
    }
</style>

<div id="content">
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(columnName:"index",header:"serial")
    ))
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In ajax load use.....
**GET** request to refresh the *grid* instead of **POST**

[Below URL helped me to solve this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903420/paging-sorting-not-working-on-web-grid-used-in-partial-view)